# Remove duplication of rows while joining multiple tables - Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

**media**

```
id  | title   | ...
1   | a song  |
2   | a video |
```

**media setting**

```
media_id  | setting_id  | chosen_option
  1       |    1        |    2
  1       |    2        |    3
  2       |    1        |    1
  2       |    2        |    4
```

So I have media table with various infromation about user uploaded media files and they have two settings `1.privacy( option-1 for public and option-2 for private)` and `2.age-safty( option-3 is for all and option-4 is for adult only)`. Now when a user(adult) searching  for a media, suppose with a title starts with `a....`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
m.id AS media_id, m.title AS media_title, 
ms.setting_id AS setting, ms.chosen_option as opt 
FROM media m 
LEFT JOIN media_setting ms ON m.id = ms.media_id
WHERE m.title LIKE 'a%'
```

AND It will give me an output with duplicate rows one row with each setting which I don't want.

So what i want is :

```
media_id  |  media_title  | setting_1  | option_for_1 |  setting_2 | option_for_2

1         |  a song       |   1        |    2         |    2        |     3
2         |  a video      |   1        |    1         |    2        |     4
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: sorry. corrected @Strawberry

Comment: Also, note that option is a reserved word, so I don't think this is your query

Comment: I just replicated my situation . No the actual query @Strawberry

Comment: If it was me, I'd stick with the query you've got, and resolve the display issues in application code. Although, that said, I wonder if the value for `setting_1` can ever be anything other than '1', and likewise for `setting_2`

Comment: value for the settings are fixed `setting_1=1 and setting_2=2` @Strawberry

Comment: Is the number of settings fixed? You are showing **two** settings. If you need dynamic number of settings, then MySQL cannot do it. That would require something similar to a pivot functionality.

Comment: For now it's 2. But yes it can increase in future @TheImpaler

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, I'd stick with the query you've got, and resolve the display issues in application code.

But anyway, here's a standard (and non-dynamic) approach in sql...

```
CREATE TABLE media
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO media VALUES
(1,'a song'),
(2,'a video');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS media_setting;

CREATE TABLE media_setting
(media_id INT NOT NULL
,setting_id INT NOT NULL
,chosen_option INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(media_id,setting_id)
);

INSERT INTO media_setting VALUES
(1,1,2),
(1,2,3),
(2,1,1),
(2,2,4);

SELECT m.*
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.setting_id = 1 THEN chosen_option END) option_for_1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.setting_id = 2 THEN chosen_option END) option_for_2
  FROM media m
  LEFT
  JOIN media_setting s 
    ON s.media_id = m.id
 GROUP
    BY m.id;

+----+---------+--------------+--------------+
| id | title   | option_for_1 | option_for_2 |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | a song  |            2 |            3 |
|  2 | a video |            1 |            4 |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Strawberry.

Comment: Everything went right except i had a part  `sum(num_of_like)` in my select query which doubled the actual value. I would like to know if you have solution @Strawberry

Comment: Don't have that bit. The column doesn't appear in the data set, anyway.